# Conditional replace of values in a column with another columns values in Pnadas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I hope this is not a duplicate question. I am trying to replace the values of a column in a dataframe with nonzero values of other dataframe's columns. Here is an small example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'x': [1, 2, 3], 'y': ["", "", 4], 'z': ["", 5, ""]}
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['A','B','C'], data=d)
df.replace('', 0, inplace=True) # replace empty cells with zeros
print(df)
 x  y  z
A  1  0  0
B  2  0  5
C  3  4  0
```

Now, if there is any nonzero elements in column y or column z, replace the values of column x (which are in the same location as y az columns) with the nonzeros.

```
df.loc[(df.y > 0), 'x'] = df.y
df.loc[(df.z > 0), 'x'] = df.z
print(df)
   x    y   z
A   1   0   0
B   5   0   5
C   4   4   0
```

The problem is that the dataframe I am dealing with has 100 columns and it wont make sense to do this process for each column individually. I am looking for the most **efficient**  way to perform this task. Thnaks for any suggestions.

Comment: Not clear, and you want to replace y with nonzero z ? or replace x with nonzero z as well

Comment: @WeNYoBen replace x with nonzero values of y and z.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

```
s=df.replace('', np.nan).drop('x',1).ffill(1).iloc[:,-1]
df.x=np.where(s.isnull(),df.x,s)
df
Out[285]: 
     x  y  z
A  1.0      
B  5.0     5
C  4.0  4
```